# how to use Profile information for payments

Tags: commerce

I am using the customer_profile_type_ui as a way of displaying different checkout pages for different types of purchases. (this is the exact scenario which the readme file described as its use, and I followed it). But now I have an issue: payments. I am using the Authorize.net contrib, and it says in its home page -

> The Payment checkout pane must come after the Billing information checkout pane for Drupal Commerce to be able to populate the order used to generate transactions with a billing address before this module attempts to process payment.

When you follow the profile_type_ui readme, it says to use rules to disable all panes (which would include 'billing information' and then enable the appropriate profile pane. I followed this advice, because the billing pane didn't have all the fields I wanted.

When I looked at the email invoice (developer email), it did not have values for the billing information, as expected (or shipping, but I'm selling memberships, so we wont be using shipping).

The only possible thing I saw was a checkbox on the billing page settings page which said

> Enable profile copying on this checkout pane, helping customers avoid having to enter the same address twice.

but it didn't do anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using a custom module with instructions that run counter to the Authorize.Net instructions. Is that what you mean by customer_profile_type_ui? I assume that isn't part of the core Commerce Customer module, so a link would be helpful, but honestly it looks like you've already answered your own question.

I don't really get why you'd disable the core Billing information checkout pane for having insufficient fields. If you add a field to your billing customer profile type, it will show up in the checkout form. What else would you need to do besides that?

Comment: I needed to do what I did because I need to have different profile fields show up on the checkout page based on different purchase types.